# Chrome extension assistance needed

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom

I am trying to get certain elements of a website to be clicked on in a specific order but I am having a bit of trouble doing so. Here is what I have so far:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches":    ["http://www.finishline.com/*", "https://www.finishline.com/*"],
        "js":         ["size.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
      }      

      {
        "matches":    ["http://www.finishline.com/*", "https://www.finishline.com/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
      }
    ]
}
```

size.js:

```
document.getElementById('10').click();
```

content.js:

```
document.getElementById('buttonAddToCart').click();
```

Here is a sample page for which I want this to work on (when link is clicked I want size 10 added to the cart): http://www.finishline.com/store/product?A=32440&categoryId=cat301568&productId=prod771501